# Drop temporary table when exiting function that return a JSON in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm new on PostgreSQL and I want to know why my temporary table is not dropped after a return different to return query.

I can execute this function many times without a "table already exists" error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_table()
   RETURNS TABLE (response JSON)
AS $$
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_test_table AS SELECT * FROM Users;
    RETURN QUERY SELECT '{"name": "Moises"}'::JSON;
    DROP TABLE temp_test_table;
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

But in this case, after the first execution, I receive a "ERROR:  relation "temp_test_json" already exists".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_json()
   RETURNS JSON
AS $$
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_test_json AS SELECT * FROM Users;
    RETURN '{"name": "Moises"}'::JSON;
    DROP TABLE temp_test_json;
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

How return query or just return affects the temporary table when is dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RETURN` terminates the execution of the function, so execution does not reach the `DROP TABLE` statement in the second function.

Contrariwise, `RETURN QUERY` adds rows to the function result set, but does *not* terminate the execution, so `DROP TABLE` is executed in the first function.

Comment: Then, I assume the temporal table always is gonna be dropped before the function retrieves any data if the return query is not a final return.

Comment: No, the result is cached in memory.